# Variable not holding value

Tags: c#, for-loop, null

I'm working through a book that is helping me learn C#, and one of the projects is something like one of those old games one is taught in elementary powerpoint lessons. This particular example uses a for loop that defines how many exits (external doors) a room or area has.

This is an example of moving through an external door. When I go back through the door, using the "MoveToANewLocation()" method, "currentLocation" loses it's value. The for loop subsequently sets the value to a negative, resulting in an error.

```
private void MoveToANewLocation(Location newLocation)
    {
        currentLocation = newLocation;

        exits.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < currentLocation.Exits.Length; i++)
        {
            exits.Items.Add(currentLocation.Exits[i].Name);
        }

        exits.SelectedIndex = 0;

        description.Text = currentLocation.Description;

        if (currentLocation is IHasExteriorDoor)
        {
            goThroughTheDoor.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            goThroughTheDoor.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```

I have a reference example that is exactly the same as the above, which works. I am stumped as to why currentLocation is losing it's value when the button "goThroughTheDoor" invokes the "MoveToANewLocation()" method.

*Apologies if this is unclear, I am still very new to modern programming*

Comment: In what scope is `currentLocation` defined?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "scope"?

Comment: where is it declared ?

Comment: In your code, it cannot be seen where `currentLocation` is defined. Perhaps it is initialized over and over again? Please show a bit more of the code.

Comment: Could you also show the code of the `goThroughTheDoor`button handler?

Comment: Ah. This is used in the form code (form1.cs), it is only called by a button on the form.




button:  
`private void goThroughTheDoor_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IHasExteriorDoor hasDoor = currentLocation as IHasExteriorDoor;
            MoveToANewLocation(hasDoor.DoorLocation);`
        }

Comment: what is exits, currentLocation.Exits share current location class the parameter you are passing in method

Comment: I am assuming that `currentLocation` is a class member. The only place where `currentLocation` is changing its value is at the beginning of the method, so maybe the problem is related to your `newLocation` parameter and not with the `MoveToANewLocation` method. You should post some more code to make things a bit more clear.

Comment: This is the entire form1.cs code: http://pastebin.com/ZRzSPzcT

Comment: It's an example from Head Start C# book?

Comment: Just use some diff utilities to compare sample code and your code. It might be the fastest way.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan - exits is the combobox control that has the adjacent rooms. Exits is `public Location[] Exits;`

Comment: @qxg already done, no differences whatsoever.

Comment: Are your `frontYard` and `backYard` members implementing `IHasExteriorDoor`? If so, then you are not setting their `DoorLocation` member. That is initialised to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

When the `MoveToANewLocation` method begins, it sets `currentLocation` to a copy of the parameter, `newLocation`:

```
//currentLocation = newLocation;
```

The `currentLocation` goes out of scope when the method exits and the garbage collector can clean up to use that memory for in scope objects. This explains how its value is lost after exiting the method.

Comment: According to the question, 'currentLocation' already looses its value inside the method and not when the method exits (see the description that the for loop inside the method causes an error because 'currentLocation' has no value). Therefore I think this does not answer the question.